$\int (\sin^6(x) + \cos^6(x))\,dx$ only using change of variables and basic trigonometric and integral properties
I'm stuck trying to solve this integral: $\int (\sin^6(x) + \cos^6(x))\,dx$. It was in an exam, I asked friends and even another teacher, but they didn't know how to solve it either, the catch is you can only use change of variables and basic integration and trigonometric facts, since that's all we had learned by the time we took the exam. I asked the teacher during the exam and he  gave me a hint: "Use trigonometric properties", so I tried the following:
First notice that
$$
(\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x))^3 = 1^3 = 1 = \sin^6(x) + 3\sin^4(x)\cos^2(x) + 3\sin^2(x)\cos^4(x) + \cos^6(x) 
$$
Then notice that
$$
\sin^6(x)+\cos^6(x) = 1 - 3\sin^4(x)\cos^2(x) - 3\sin^2(x)\cos^4(x) \\
\sin^6(x)+\cos^6(x) = 1 - 3\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)(\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)) \\
\sin^6(x)+\cos^6(x) = 1 - 3\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)
$$
And now hopefully we have a simpler integral:
$\int (1 - 3\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x))\,dx = \int 1 \,dx - 3\int\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)\,dx$
but I can't find an appropriate change of variable for this integral, if I set $u = \sin(x)$, then the integral would be $\int u^2\cos(x)\,du$ I end up with an extra $\cos(x)$ in there.

Using the result you already have, notice that $\sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x)$, so that:
$$ \sin^6(x) + \cos^6(x) = 1 - \frac{3}{4} \sin^2(2x)$$
$$ = 1 - \frac{3}{4}\left( \frac{1-\cos(4x)}{2} \right)$$
$$ = \left( \frac{5+3\cos(4x)}{8} \right).$$
Which integrates easily to:
$$\frac{5x}{8} + \frac{3\sin(4x)}{32}.$$
(I checked it with mathematica)

Hint
$$\int\sin^2x\cos^2x\mathrm dx=\frac14\int\left(2\sin x\cos x\right)^2\mathrm dx=\frac14\int (\sin 2x)^2\mathrm dx$$
Can you take it from here?

Since
$$\begin{align}
a^6 + b^6 &= (a^2 + b^2)(a^4 - a^2 b^2 + b^4) \\
&= (a^2 + b^2)((a^2 + b^2)^2 - 3a^2 b^2), \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
it follows that
$$\begin{align}
\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x &= (\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)((\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)^2 + 2 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x) \\
&= 1 - 3 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x \\
&= 1 - \frac{3}{4} \sin^2 2x \\
&= \frac{5}{8} + \frac{3}{8}\left(1 - 2 \sin^2 2x \right) \\
&= \frac{5}{8} + \frac{3}{8} \cos 4x.\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\int \cos^6 x + \sin^6 x \, dx = \frac{1}{8} \int 5 + 3 \cos 4x \, dx = \frac{1}{8} \left(5x + \frac{3}{4} \sin 4x\right) + C. \tag{3}$$
